# How to overlay one 3d model over another in arcore android app

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to make a POC trial room app and I've a 3d model of human body and another 3d model of a t-shirt in my app. How do I anchor the t-shirt model around the human so that they are coupled together.
As far as I know arcore currently only detects points on a plane so how do I tweak this to make it identify points on the human model and fit t-shirt on top of it?

If not arcore, what other android library can I use to make this POC?

Answer (score 1):

ARCore won't detect the points of a 3D model that you place in the scene; it doesn't need to. You have this information already because you control the 3D model.

What you want to do sounds more like a 3D modelling problem than one with ARCore. I would use a 3D modelling tool to overlay the t-shirt and human body models, such that they shared a center point. Then re-export the two models separately, since it sounds like you're going for a customisable t-shirt experience.

Reattaching them should then be as simple as anchoring both models to the same anchor point through ARCore / Sceneform, such that they share the same local geometry.